# Transform SOAP Request with XSLT | For Each Loop Issue

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, soap, nintex-workflow

I have a SOAP Request that looks like the following;

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCountriesResponse xmlns="url">
      <GetCountriesResult>
        <ExtendedOptionItem>
          <Value>GB</Value>
          <Description>United Kingdom</Description>
          <Active>true</Active>
          <IsDefault>true</IsDefault>
          <Order>0</Order>
        </ExtendedOptionItem>
        <ExtendedOptionItem>
          <Value>GB</Value>
          <Description>United Kingdom</Description>
          <Active>true</Active>
          <IsDefault>true</IsDefault>
          <Order>0</Order>
        </ExtendedOptionItem>
      </GetCountriesResult>
    </GetCountriesResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My XSLT at the moment specifically targets the "Description" node. What I'd like to do is pull out the description for each "ExtendedOptionItem".

I have written some XSLT that will need to separate each description with a semi-colon.

This XSLT works absolutely fine when there is only one "ExtendedOptionItem". However when there are multiple items the XML is not transformed.

Please can you review my XSLT and evaluate where I'm going wrong;

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:for-each xmlns:n="url" select="n:ExtendedOptionItem">
<xsl:value-of select="n:Description" />;</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Many thanks

UPDATE;

The SOAP response is modified by the Workflow Engine to appear as follows;

```
<ExtendedOptionItem xmlns="url"><Value>GB</Value><Description>United Kingdom</Description><Active>true</Active><IsDefault>true</IsDefault><Order>0</Order></ExtendedOptionItem><ExtendedOptionItem xmlns="url"><Value>AF</Value><Description>Afghanistan</Description><Active>true</Active><IsDefault>false</IsDefault><Order>0</Order></ExtendedOptionItem><ExtendedOptionItem xmlns="url"><Value>AX</Value><Description>Åland Islands</Description><Active>true</Active><IsDefault>false</IsDefault><Order>0</Order></ExtendedOptionItem>
```

Comment: Your "updated" response is not well-formed XML and cannot be processed by XSLT.

Comment: Okay thank you for pointing out. I've reformed the XML and it now works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This XSLT works absolutely fine when there is only one
>   "ExtendedOptionItem".

No, it doesn't.

The problem is that your template matches the `/` root node - and `ExtendedOptionItem` is not a child of the  `/` root node. As a result, your:

```
<xsl:for-each xmlns:n="url" select="n:ExtendedOptionItem">
```

selects nothing. Try changing it to:

```
<xsl:for-each xmlns:n="url" select="//n:ExtendedOptionItem">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've updated the code as per your suggestion and it still has the same behaviour. Do you have any other suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: "*Do you have any other suggestions?*" No, because I cannot reproduce your problem - see: http://xsltransform.net/bnnZXc

Comment: Okay, I may have noticed something Nintex is doing with the SOAP response. It seems to be removing some elements and so the response looks different. I'll update the Question to reflect;